# Add a bookmark to chrome which opens the 'new tab' page

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I'm setting up Chrome for my mum and she's a bit of a technophobe. I want her to be able to launch everything she uses from the bookmarks bar. This is fine for bookmarking sites like Facebook and Amazon, but I'd like to let her to have a link to the 'new tab' page -- this will let her see her installed games from the app store. It'll keep everything consistent if I can make her a bookmark called 'apps' or 'home' or similar.

So, does anyone know a way to create a bookmark or bookmarklet which will open a new tab pointing to the 'new tab' page? I don't know of any page like `about:new-tab` which will open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create such a bookmark by simply opening the New Tab page and **clicking the star icon.**

The URL is:

```
chrome://newtab
```

You can also enable the "Home" button, which links to the same page, via *Settings → Basics → Toolbar → Show Home button*.

[image: Home button screenshot]